# Pasar datos entre archivos .php

Tags: php, html

me pueden ayudar en una duda
Tengo un archivo llamado a.php y otro b.php
Necesito pasar gran cantidad de datos desde el archivo a.php a el archivo b.php
Lo estoy haciendo con el metodo GET de la siguiente manera :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la barra del URL se llena excesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien conoce un metodo mas efectivo ?

Comment: método POST? en lugar de GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sesiones http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

al principio de a.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

$_SESSION['datosAEnviar'] = '';
```

y reemplaza el get en el header location con estas lineas

```
$_SESSION['datosAEnviar'] = $Datos_comentarios; 
header("location:b.php");
```

luego al principio de b.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$Datos_comentarios = 
   isset($_SESSION['datosAEnviar']) ? $_SESSION['datosAEnviar'] : 'NoHayDatos';
/*  
    a partir de este momento $Datos_comentarios contiene lo que enviaste 
    o el texto "NoHayDatos" 
*/
```

al final del proceso en b.php destruyes el dato y la sesión

```
unset($_SESSION['datosAEnviar']);
session_destroy();
```